# Как сделать ожидание потоком нажатия клавиши в console application

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Идет поток, к примеру, от 0 до 20. У меня есть число в txt файле, к примеру, 9. Мне надо,чтобы когда поток дошел до 9, то программа ждала когда я нажму на кнопку.  Через abort не выходило, единственное что пошло это было return; но опять же программа просто закрывалась, как будто я прописал  if(..==..) { Environment.Exit(0); }

Код весь мой:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console.Application1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(thread1);
            th.Start();
            Thread th1 = new Thread(thread2);
            th1.Start();
        }
        static void thread1()
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Users\Desktop\test.txt");
                string st = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string s1a = z;
                Console.WriteLine("First thread:" + " " + s1a);
                if (st == s1a)
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();//если совпало то стоп и все потоки тоже стоп
                }
            }
        }
        static void thread2()
        {
            for (int z = 10; z < 20; z++)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Users\Desktop\test.txt");
                string st = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string s1a = z;
                Console.WriteLine("First thread:" + " " + s1a);
                if (st == s1a)
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();//если совпало то стоп и все потоки тоже стоп
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console,ReadKey()?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37153/discussion-on-question-by-wiz-khalifaaaaa------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша программа завершает работу раньше времени, т.к. после запуска потоков, прекращается выполнение основного потока программы. Решается просто - добавьте `Console.ReadLine()` или любой другой `Console.ReadXXX()` в конец метода `Main`

Измените код поиска в потоке, так чтобы он завершался когда найдет значение, например так:

```
static void thread1()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Users\Desktop\test.txt"))
    {
        string st = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    string s1a;
    int z = 0;
    do
    {   
        s1a = z;
        Console.WriteLine("First thread:" + " " + s1a);
        z++;
    }
    while ((z < 10) && (st != s1a));
}
```

В таком варианте, функция и поток, созданный для нее, будет выполняться только до момента нахождения искомого значения. Чтение файла вынесено из цикла и использована конструкция `using` для гарантированного закрытия файла после чтения.

Принудительное завершение потоков можно сделать так:

```
while (th.IsAlive && th1.IsAlive);// ждем завершения любого потока
th.Abort();
th1.Abort();
```

Но чтобы увидеть эффект сделайте циклы поиска более длинными.

Comment: последний кусок оказался лучше

Comment: @Wiz_Khalifaaaaa Вообще если все это переписать через Task и asinc/await будет компактнее и немного проще

Comment: @Wiz_Khalifaaaaa Если остались вопросы, задавайте. сегодня я уже спать, а завтра дополню, если что-то осталось непонятным.

Comment: Не спорю, я сделал еще проще, и то что у меня вышло(за ваш код, благодарен тоже)вообще облегчило задачу сразу, я просто сделал что если номер найден то софт его записывает в txt на раб столе(отлично(а так в софте пришлось его смотреть)) и я открываю и вижу совпадение. И сам софт закрывается после того как нашел. На мой взгляд - это лучшее что я мог придумать)))

Comment: Вопросов больше нет! Благодарю еще раз за потраченное время на меня!

Comment: @Wiz_Khalifaaaaa если ответ является решением вашей проблемы, отметьте его галочкой, когда пройдет таймаут. Даже на простой вопрос можно получить хороший развернутый ответ если вопрос хорошо оформлен. Я правда не очень понимаю как исправить заголовок, чтобы он соответствовал вопросу....

Comment: Блин, забыл спросит(вылетало из головы) как сделать чтобы все потоки шли равномерно, то есть чтобы не было так что один быстрее другого ?

Comment: @Wiz_Khalifaaaaa а вот об этом вы можете задать новый вопрос.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin я просисвл так: Threads.Sleep(0);